# Найти под процесс c#

Tags: c#, процесс

Коллеги, доброго времени суток.
Не могу понять как мне выцепить под процесс в процессе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть процесс который достаточно легко отловить.

Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("GGnet");
Он мне отдаёт
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

только ОДИН первый процесс который находит в под процессе.
Не могу понять как мне взять все эти процессы ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1336376/220553

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в C# получить ProcessID всех дочерних процессов, процесса который запущен с помощью System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1336322/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-processid-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%81)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не один из методов не работает